# How to Implement concurrency in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, mvvm, concurrency

I have two **Person** and **PersonDTO** classes and I'm using **NHibernate** to save these objects. As while as I have One user there is no problem and as soon as another user is going to update the object that another user is updating it. then Both of the can update the same object and because it is updated by another user, on of the changes will lost.

In order to implement cuncurrency I used two ways that both of them faced with problem.

- **The first solution :** Use the **Person** constructor to update the object
- **The second approach :** Using a **GetByID** method

The first approach is working great with any problem but unfortunately I don't have enough permition to the Load **Person** completetly with its dependencies. so that I have to use the second approach.

In the second approach when I set (update) **Version** it is o up to the last second, but NHibernate is using its old Version so that my changes won't apply.

Look at the following Code

**load a Person by ID**

```
person = locator.PersonRepository.GetById(dto.Id);
```

Version field is loaded by new value. but I need to set it from my **PersonDTO** object

```
person.Version = dto.Version
```

During update process NHibernate passes **old value** to sql and I don't face with concurreny error.

What should I do to implement concurrency in this way. 
Any help is appriciated.

Comment: Have you configured Person.Version property as version field in your mapping?

Comment: Yes of course.  the first solution work correct, But second approach is a problem.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. If you've configured versioning correctly on your objects, NH should look after concurrency conflicts for you ...?

Can you elaborate a little bit more?

Comment: During Update Person,I am forced to load instance of Person by GetByID() method Whereas person loaded again, 
So version of this person is changed and last version,
So Nhibernate does not seen error.
I must set version of loaded Person handy. But it does not apply.

Comment: I have the same issue. I would like to set Version property on entity update, so that it will throw StaleException when versions differ. But NH ignores this version property being changed.

Comment: Maybe just implement interceptor http://weblogs.asp.net/stefansedich/archive/2008/10/01/set-the-value-of-a-version-column-in-nhibernate-manually.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand your problem, I guess You have a field that its **getter** works fine but when you are trying to **set** it you face with problem, if it is so, then check the following considerations

- Check if your **Version** field that is not Readonly
- Check if it has a **public setter** not a **private** one
- Check if you have needed properties in your **Mapper**
- Check what is happening in your **Person** constructor that is not raise when you use **GetByID** method

provide more information if these ideas didn't help you

Comment: No my problem is another thing. I quess Nhibernate when load object, keeps orginal version for object, But in using of constructor, this object is transient and set version field for first time is allowed.

Comment: @ehsanzeynali As your object is **Transient** and Nhibernate is setting its **Version** field for the first time, Actually you cannot change the Version until update process so that using **GetByID** is meaningless in my opinion.

Comment: Set version field In operation is allowed, But in fact Does not apply. So why is setting allowed. Why version field is not private?

Comment: @ehsanzeynali Are you sure that **Version** does not have any relation to other TABLES ? I mean may be its value setted in some tables as a **foreignkey** and so that you can't change it until you change the relations.

Answer (score 2):

Ayende has an [interesting article](http://ayende.com/blog/3946/nhibernate-mapping-concurrency) on the different types of concurrency supported by nHibernate. If you setup a version column then nHibernate will manage the value of the version automatically and throw a `StaleObjectException` when you try to update an object that has become stale.

You can use this exception to notify the user or implement a more complicated automatic concurrency resolution method.

Comment: I read this article, But my problem is another thing. I write a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like following

class

```
public class Person
{
    public virtual DateTime Version { get; set; }
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    .
}
```

Map Person.version property as version field on Mapping file.

```
<version name="Version" column="Version" type="timestamp" unsaved-value="1/1/0001" />
```

and update code like following

```
var person = session.Get(personDto.Id);
person.Version = personDto.Version
person.FirstName = personDto.FirstName
session.SaveOrUpdate(person);
```

Once you enable show sql and run it, you should see like following

```
UPDATE [Person] 
SET Version = @p0, FirstName = @p1 
WHERE PersonId = @p3 AND Version = @p4;
```

Comment: No my problem is another thing. I quess Nhibernate when load object, keeps orginal version for object, But in using of constructor, this object is transient and set version field for first time is allowed. Set version field In operation is allowed, But in fact Does not apply. So why is setting allowed. Why version field is not private?